# Need help understand how this particular grep works

Tags: grep

```
cat foo.txt | grep "a|b|x"
```

foo.txt has a and x.

This command returns nothing even though I would have assumed to return a & x. How does this command get parsed?

```
cat foo.txt
a
x
xcd $  cat foo.txt | grep "a|b|x"
xcd $ 
xcd $ grep -E -w 'a|b|x' foo.txt
xcd $ a
      x
```

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for by doing something like this: grep -E -w 'a|b|x' foo.txt

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and read [ask] for a better experience here. Note `grep "a|b|x"` does not understand pipes as "ors" but as literal pipes. So you either have to escape them or use -E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grep OR you should use as below;

```
grep "a\|b\|x" foo.txt
```

eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ grep "a\|b\|x" foo.txt
a
x
```

cat foo.txt | grep "a|b|x" command finds "a|b|x" as a word

eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat foo.txt
a|b|x
a
x
user@host:/tmp$ cat foo.txt | grep "a|b|x"
a|b|x
```

grep -E option is for extended regexp. this is also "grep OR"